# Modulo algorithm with byte array and 8 bit integer: 8bit = bytes % 8bit

Tags: c, algorithm, modulo

I need to create an algorithm implemented in C that do modulo arithmetic between an arbitrary number of bytes and one byte. See this:

```
typedef struct{
    u_int8_t * data;
    u_int16_t length;
}UBigInt;
u_int8_t UBigIntModuloWithUInt8(UBigInt a,u_int8_t b){

}
```

For powers of two a & (b-1) can be used but what about non powers of two?

I realise one method is: a - b*(a/b)

That would require to use UBigIntDivisionWithUInt8 and UBigIntMultiplicationWithUInt8 and UBigIntSubtractionWithUBigInt. There might be a more efficient way to do this?

Thank you.

This is the implementation I now have:

```
u_int8_t UBigIntModuloWithUInt8(UBigInt a,u_int8_t b){
    if (!(b & (b - 1)))
        return a.data[a.length - 1] & b - 1; // For powers of two this can be done
    // Wasn't a power of two.
    u_int16_t result = 0; // Prevents overflow in calculations
    for(int x = 0; x < a.length; x++) {
        result *= (256 % b);
        result %= b;
        result += a.data[x] % b;
        result %= b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: you say `a` is an arbitrary # of bytes; what if anything can you say about b ? is it constant? if so what value?

Comment: I think `b` is an arbitrary 8-bit (unsigned?) integer.

Comment: b could be 1-255. I need to implement it for 58 but there might be more cases. If there is some specifically optimised solution for 58, then that would be good but I will likely need to implement it for any.

Comment: i imagine there's a reason why you cannot/do not want [GMP](http://gmplib.org/) ? ~which has many optimisations built in, even targetting specific processors, almost like the folk who wrote it live for this kind of thing ;)

Comment: I looked into it and it gave me a headache. :-) If I could cannibalise just the parts I need, it would be good but I can't make my way around that library. Is there code in that library or another that I can take from? I found a library called BigDigits though it uses 32bit integers and not 8bit integers like I want. :-(

Comment: I'm going to take a look at OpenSSL which has bignums. Also I need to use cryptography and I realise now that the ECDRSA algorithm I need requires bignums and OpenSSL includes ECDRSA. I'll see...

Comment: lol, i think your headaches are assured whichever path you choose. have you looked at [libTom](http://libtom.org) i've not used this so i have no idea what it's like but it claims to support algos like Montgomery Reduction, which might be good for you if you were only dealing with a small range of moduli

Comment: OpenSSL seems to be pretty good. I'll give it a go and I might modify such as to remove unnecessary parts and ensure it matches the format for my libraries documentation so I can include it in my documentation.

Comment: OpenSSL uses "unsigned int" and not bytes. Since C memory blocks and arrays are supposed to be contiguous (right), I guess conversion is not an issue?

Comment: @MatthewMitchell - Depends on the direction of the conversion: you can cast (unsigned int*) to (char*) alright, but the opposite might go terribly wrong: pointer alignment. Also, you could try using MPIR, it is explicitly designed to be easy to use and based on GMP.

Comment: I think I'll make my own simple bignum code for the basic algorithm I need and perhaps interface with another library for the cryptography stuff which might use it's own bignum thing. The bignum code I'm making is specific to the requirements. I could implement my own ECDSA algorithm but that would probably be very hard.

Comment: @MatthewMitchell I think you lack a check for `b=0` ( !(b&(b-1)) is true for b = 0, so you're dividing by 256 ) and also, as aesthetic feature, you could wrap `b - 1` in parenthesis. It made me nervous until I checked the operator precedence table for C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a variation on Horner's method.
Process a byte by byte with this formula:
`a % b = ((a // 256) % b) * (256 % b) + (a % 256) % b`, where x // y is the rounding division (normal C integer division). The reason this will work is that congruence modulo b is an equivalence relation.
With this you have an `O(length)` algorithm, or `O(log(a))`.
Example snippet (untested, my C skills are rusty):

```
u_int16_t result = 0; // Just in case, to prevent overflow
for(i = 0, i<a.length; i++) {
    result *= (256 % b);
    result %= b;
    result += (a[i] % b);
    result %= b;
}
```

Some justification:
`a = (a // 256) * 256 + (a % 256)`, therefore
`a % b = ((a // 256) * 256) % b + ((a % 256) % b)`. However `a % 256 = a[n-1]` and `a // 256 = a[0 .. n-2]`. Reversing the actions in a way similar to Horner's rule gives you the presented snippet.

Comment: I have no idea how this works but from a single test it seems to. Will implement it and test and et back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I tested it in Python (has native support for arbitrary-sized ints) with this code: http://codepad.org/Eo00RNEJ Didn't seem to give any errors after 2 minutes of cycling, so I guess it's ok ;) Note that I haven't covered division by zero.

Comment: I added a test for powers of two, fixed the for loop and put up the code I have.